# delegate or make ajax call a component in react

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, reactjs

As you can see in the code below my ajax (i'm using fetch) is located within a handleSearch function, in App component. How can I delegate and make the ajax call in its own component? I come from angular 1, in angular there's thing like services/factories but I'm not sure how to do it in react.

```
const App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      username: '',
      profiles: [],
      noUser : false
    }
  },
  handleInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      username: e.target.value
    })
  },
  handleSearch() {
    if (!this.state.username) {
      alert('username cannot be empty');
      return false;
    }
    fetch('https://api.github.com/search/users?q=' + this.state.username)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json()
      }).then(json => {
        this.setState({
          profiles: json.items
        })

        if(json.items.length === 0){
          this.setState({noUsers : true});
        }else{
          this.setState({noUsers : false});
        }
      })
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Github username" onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={this.state.username} />
            <button onClick={this.handleSearch}>Search</button>
            {this.state.profiles.length > 0 &&
              <Users profiles={this.state.profiles} />
            }
            {this.state.noUsers &&
              <p>No users found.</p>
            }
          </div>
    )
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/eldyvoon/pen/ENMXQz this code need much refactoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not everything in React has to be a component. It is still essentially plain old Javascript underneath. Extract the API logic out into it's own module/file, e.g.

**GithubApi.js**

```
module.exports.getUsers = function(username) {
  return fetch('https://api.github.com/search/users?q=' + username)
  .then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
}
```

And then use it where ever it is required:

```
var GithubApi = require('/path/to/GithubApi.js');

const App = React.createClass({
  ..
  ..
  handleSearch() {
    if (!this.state.username) {
      alert('username cannot be empty');
      return false;
    }
    GithubApi.getUsers(this.state.username)
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          profiles: json.items
        })

        if(json.items.length === 0){
          this.setState({noUsers : true});
        }else{
          this.setState({noUsers : false});
        }
      })
  },
  ..
  ..
```

This is just an example - how you want to design your module is up to you, depending on how specific or flexible, etc. you want it to be.

Comment: great I got a picture.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write it in it's own React component, just write a plain old Javascript CommonJS module and either load it via require() or pass it in as a prop.

Comment: like how? pass it as a prop means it has to be a react component right?

Comment: No. A prop can be anything. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: why are you ask me to read proptypes? it's checking the type, does it related to component spliting?

Comment: proptypes explains what properties can be passed into a component, such as an object (which is what you'd want in this case).